# React App not working in internet explorer (empty div)

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer

React app is working fine in Google chrome but not in Internet explorer 
you can check that on https://provisionwizard.azurewebsites.net/

i tried polyfils (It's not working)
still same issue

Answer (score 0):

You have this error in IE:

```
'fetch' is undefined
```

You have two options:

1 polyfill "fetch" in your ReactJS via external script link

```
<script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=fetch"></script>
```

2 add fetch from npm package, for example "isomorphic-unfetch".

```
import fetch from "isomorphic-unfetch";
```

Comment: If this solution works for you, check answer as acepted to close it.

Comment: You have to use one or the second option. If you could show your source code, it would be easier to debug.